# Where did my .run file install

Tags: lubuntu

I downloaded `SolarCoin_2.0.8_64bit.run` onto my Lubuntu installation.  After downloading some additional packages I did the following:

```
cd /home/user/Downloads
chmod +x SolarCoin_2.0.8_64bit.run
sudo ./SolarCoin_2.0.8_64bit.run
```

On installation the program starts. After a restart of the machine, there is no shortcut to launch the program. I looked in `/usr/share/applications` but `solarcoin-qt` is not present.

`solarcoin-qt` is present in `/home/user/Downloads/SolarCoin_2.0.8_64bit` but attempting to execute it from there leads to an error.

How do I launch this program?  Does it somehow need to be installed to a different location?

I tried the command `whereis solarcoin-qt`, it gives no results.

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: it is probably not in the path, when you installed the process should video where is installing, however, try open a shell and type "solar" following TAB key twice and see if bash will complete and if there is any luck you will see some name appearing, probably the executable name is different

Comment: solar TAB TAB revealed nothing.  I cant replicate the error now solarcoin-qt file has vanished....

Comment: perhaps its a good idea to remove this and try again, how do I un-install from the command line

Comment: Please do not ask new questions in the comments. If you have a new question, please ask a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and run the script again with a leading `strace`.

```
sudo strace -e write ./SolarCoin_2.0.8_64bit.run
```

and check the written files. These files were written and/or created during the installation.

And as you say, you can see a SIGCHLD; this means that the installation has been completed incorrectly. For this reason you may not see the expected files.

Comment: Ok I did that, Im unclear how to read the result:
write (1, "printf is a shell builtin\n", 26) = 26
write (1, "Creating directory SolarCoin_2.0"..., 41Creating directory SolarCoin_2.0.8_64bit
) = 41

then a bunch more stuff starting
--- SIGCHILD

How does that help me?  Thanks

Comment: You see a list of created/written (installed) files and the SIGCHLD means, there is an error during the installation of `SolarCoin_2.0.8_64bit.run`.

Comment: @Scalextrix: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @A.B. is there a way to understand what went wrong?  I reported the error on the SolarCoin forum but if there is a way to give more detail that would be useful?
Im a Linux Noob so its for my understanding too, thanks.